# GRPC 20908 ssl_transport_security.cc:1575] No match found for server name: 0.0.0.0

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, grpc

My server and client are in the same machine. My server is in Node.js, my client in PHP. My server is running on 0.0.0.0:50053, my client 127.0.0.1:80. So my client sends a request to the server, if I use insecure connection, everything works, but if I add SSL (Im using mutual TLS) my server tells me:

E0518 16:20:47.295923933   20908 ssl_transport_security.cc:1575] No match found for server name: 0.0.0.0.

- I made root cert with CN (Common Name):  localhost (my CA is me, the
  same machine) - rootCA.crt.
- I made server cert and signed with    rootCA.crt CN (Common
  Name):   0.0.0.0 - server.crt.
- I made client cert    and signed with rootCA.crt CN (Common
  Name):   localhost - client.crt.

So, it looks like when I run my server, it checks the certificates, and CN (Common Name):   0.0.0.0 is not a good name.

So I changed the IP of server to 127.0.0.2 and created a new cert for server with CN (Common Name): 127.0.0.2. When I send the request I get:

21897 ssl_transport_security.cc:1575] No match found for server name: 127.0.0.2.

Same error!

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of the ip to localhost
Example works for me.

```
$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
-Subject localhost `
-DnsName localhost `
-KeyAlgorithm RSA `
-KeyLength 2048 `
-NotBefore (Get-Date) `
-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(2) `
-CertStoreLocation "cert:CurrentUser\My" `
-FriendlyName "Localhost Certificate for .NET Core" `
-HashAlgorithm SHA256 `
-KeyUsage DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment, DataEncipherment `
-TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") 
$certificatePath = 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My\' + ($certificate.ThumbPrint)
```

## create temporary certificate path

```
$tmpPath = "C:\tmp"
If(!(test-path $tmpPath))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $tmpPath
}
```

## set certificate password here

```
$pfxPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123abc456def" -Force -AsPlainText
$pfxFilePath = "c:\tmp\localhost.pfx"
$cerFilePath = "c:\tmp\localhost.cer"
```

## create pfx certificate

```
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificatePath -FilePath $pfxFilePath -Password $pfxPassword
Export-Certificate -Cert $certificatePath -FilePath $cerFilePath
```

## import the pfx certificate

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfxFilePath Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $pfxPassword -Exportable
```

## trust the certificate by importing the pfx certificate into your trusted root

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath $cerFilePath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root
```

It's a powershell script

Comment: "Change the name of the ip to localhost Example works for me." You mean change it for the server?

Comment: Generating the certificate as I showed you in powershell worked for me for a gRPC service in .net core.